# SPlit string in java with delimiter

Tags: java, split

My String is  `Spiderman|Batman|Superman`
I want to split the string so that the output looks like `Spiderman Batman Superman`
I tried this:

```
String actors = "Spiderman|Batman|Superman";
String [] temp;
String delimiter = "|";

temp = actors.split(delimiter);
for (int i =0; i<temp.length; i++)
           System.out.print(temp[i].replaceAll("\\|", " "));
```

How can I do that better ? The output makes no sense. 
Thank you in anticipation. 
The output is still the same like the input. After compiling it, it shows me this:

```
Spiderman|Batman|Superman
```

It is like the split method never been started.

### Second question

Please look at this picture. If I use 100k Strings it looks like this: 
[image: screenshot of eclipse console]

Please look at the comment in my code after the for loop. MY split string works but I get a strange output. (look at the screenshot, please) I think it is caused by "print" or there is no more space for representing nearly 300 k strings. I connected my database project with eclipse. In postgres I imported a .csv file that contains several information about nearly 300k movies. Such as actors directors, year, rating etc. 
This is my problem:

This is my code in Java

```
package dbs;
import java.sql.*;

 public class Fertigevariante {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    String url= "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?user=postgres&password=password";
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);


    Statement st= conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM kinofilme");
    while (rs.next()){
        String imdib= rs.getString("imdib");
        String rating = rs.getString("rating");
        int votes = rs.getInt("votes");
        String runtime = rs.getString("runtime");
        String name = rs.getString("name");
        String directors = rs.getString("directors");
        String actors = rs.getString("actors");

        String [] temp;
        String delimiter ="|";

        temp = actors.split(delimiter);
        for(int j=0 ; j < temp.length; j++)
                System.out.print( temp[j].replaceAll("\\|", " ")); // here is the output problem, look at the screenshot I uploaded here.


        int year = rs.getInt("year");
   //   System.out.println(imdib + "\t" + name + "\t" + year + "\t" + votes + "\t" + directors + "\t" + actors);

    }
    rs.close();
    st.close();




    conn.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
 }
```

Comment: 1. Please don't submit a code that doesn't compile. 2. saying "the output makes no sense" is vague, you should be more specific: what is the current output and what is the expected output.

Comment: Same problem that was mentioned in the comment of the answer I posted: you need to escape `|`

Comment: Your second question isnt really a question. Create a new post with more details there...

Comment: @Reimeus I did it. Please have a look, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you split and then use `print` you'll get: "SpidermanBatmanSuperman"

Since you want a space in between you can replace the last line with:

```
System.out.print(temp[i] + " ");
```

But you can do even better by simply replacing the substring "|" with a space: " "

```
System.out.print("Spiderman|Batman|Superman".replaceAll("\\|", " "));
```

In both cases the output will be:

```
Spiderman Batman Superman
```

**Important**:

> when you split/replace `|` you should escape it since it's a special
>   character that has a regex-meaning!

Comment: The output is "S p i d e r m a n | B a t m a n | S u p e r m a n ... Did not work unfortunately.

Comment: @Blnpwr you should escape `|` - did you read through the rest of the answer?

Comment: Ok, now after your edit I tried the second way. It worked thank you very much. But what happens if  I have more strings? I tried it with 100k strings(imported a txt file) but the output is that one string is upon the other. Is it because of the print?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "one string is upon the other" - please update your question and provide an example. As I already mentioned: when you post a question try to write all the relevant details as: what is the requested output and what is the actual output. Submit a small code snippet that describes your problem by reproducing it - it will make it much easier to help you!

Comment: Please look at my original question. I posted a picture where you can see the problem.

Comment: @Blnpwr if you want to print each string in a separate line use `System.out.println` instead of `System.out.print`. If you simply want space - you can do what I described in the answer above.

Comment: Please look at my edited question. I edited it and it is very detailful now.

Comment: @Blnpwr looks like eclipse bug... try to print using `println` as I mentioned on the previous comment.

Comment: I tried println, then the output is very strange. It is shown as a line.
First line: S
Second line : U
3rd line : P
and so on..

Comment: @Blnpwr you're confusing two different issues, you're getting "S u p e r m a" when you don't escape the `|`. You can also try to run your main from command-line - to eliminate the option of eclipse display issue.

Comment: Well, as you see from my code , I did , what you told me. Just with the difference that I have 300k Strings now. Can you tell me surely that there is no problem with my code and it is just an eclipse bug ?

Comment: You can also try to run your main from command-line - to eliminate the option of eclipse display issue. You can also restart Eclipse - you won't believe how many times it solved problems for me...

Comment: Ok , I will try this. Could you explain shortly how to run the main from command line? You know, I always run my projects with the console in eclipse. Sorry for the noobish questions.

Comment: Compile: `javac Fertigevariante.java` and then run: `java Fertigevariante`

Answer (score 2):

You could `quote` the regex argument of [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)

```
temp = actors.split(Pattern.quote(delimiter));
```

Comment: Could you please look at my second question?

Answer (score 1):

`split` accepts regular expression as an argument - `|` is special character in regular expression. Try `"\\|"` as delimiter, or use [Pattern.quote(delimiter)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Could you please look at my second question?